# How to make a video upload and image upload faster in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

My CodeIgniter image and video upload works faster on local server

But its very slow on online linux server.
I don't know why this problem occurred?.

Comment: Maybe it's simply about network bandwidth?

Comment: How?.. Howmuch must want?...

Comment: If it works on fast on a local server it is because you are connected through a LAN which will have much higher network speeds than a remote server. How much bandwidth do you have through your broadband supplier? Also what sizes are the videos and images that your trying to upload?

Comment: 25mb videos 2 and 10mb images 3

Comment: They are small sizes so it will most likely be a slow internet connection. Goto http://www.speedtest.net/ and post a link showing your results.

Comment: downlaod speed : 2.10mbps uplaod speed : 0.39mbps

Comment: okay, using a bit of math... with your upload speed of 0.39Mbps it would take about 8.5 mins to upload your video files and about 3.5 mins to upload your images. And that is only if it uses 100% of your available connection. Your connection speed is your problem and there is nothing you can really do about that unless you can get a better internet connection.